# Use stringr::str_glue with pipes

Tags: r, stringr

I want use `str_glue` with pipes. My code:

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- c('john', 'bell', 'mary', 'cott')

x %>% 
  str_to_title(.) %>% 
  str_glue('Hi, {.}. How are you?')
```

But, the follow error message occur:

> Error: All unnamed arguments must be length 1

Desire output:

```
Hi, John. How are you?
Hi, Bell. How are you?
Hi, Mary. How are you?
Hi, Cott. How are you?
```

Comment: You can wrap the `str_glue` call in something like `purrr::map_chr`. Based on the error message, `str_glue` expects that you supply either a single value, or a named list of values, so it's clear which placeholders get which data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can wrap `str_glue` with curly braces.

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- c('john', 'bell', 'mary', 'cott')

x %>% 
    str_to_title(.) %>% 
    {str_glue('Hi, {.}. How are you?')}
#> Hi, John. How are you?
#> Hi, Bell. How are you?
#> Hi, Mary. How are you?
#> Hi, Cott. How are you?
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the help `help(str_glue)`, I came up with the following working solution. You can see the help yourself.

```r
x <- c('john', 'bell', 'mary', 'cott')
x <- data.frame(x)
rownames(x) <- x[,1]

x %>% 
str_glue_data("Hi, {rownames(.)}. How are you?")

#Hi, john. How are you?
#Hi, bell. How are you?
#Hi, mary. How are you?
#Hi, cott. How are you?
```

You can as well use just `str_glue` without using the pipe as follows (I think that is not what you want, so the above dataframe workaround)

```r
x <- c('john', 'bell', 'mary', 'cott')

str_glue('Hi, {x}. How are you?')
#Hi, john. How are you?
#Hi, bell. How are you?
#Hi, mary. How are you?
#Hi, cott. How are you?
```

Hope that helps.